# Templates for video production?

Tags: producing, video

I am planning to release short and basic videos on youtube. I would like to have a more polished look and feel so I am wondering if there are templates that you can use with, say, adobe premiere, that are complete with graphics, sounds, etc. Sorta like how a theme works with Wordpress.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Audio.SE and thanks for your question! Unfortunately, we need to close the questions that aren't really appropriate for a recording site like this one, in order to keep the site on-topic. Please don't let it discourage you from asking future audio questions though! Consult the FAQ if you're curious if a question fits or not.

Comment: Reopened now that video production is in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.premierepro.net where I'm sharing some project templates. If more people share their own templates there, it will become a great resource for free Premiere Pro templates. Everything you see on http://www.premierepro.net is free for both commercial and private use, and you can even download free sample chapters from the book "The Cool Stuff in Premiere Pro".

/jarle

Answer (score 0):

The title designer of Adobe Premiere (CS3 at least) contains some templates for on-screen overlays which look quite good.

As for sounds, I dont't think there is anything included out-of-the box.

Answer (score 0):

[Video Hive](http://videohive.net/) has several professional assets with various degrees of specificity that you can integrate to your project for a reasonable price.

Answer (score -3):

There are many companies which participate in the production of the templates of the video production. Our company provide better facilities than any other company to produce templates as well as audios and videos also. You will get all the facilities in one place.

---

[video production services](http://www.multimediamktg.com/services.html)

Comment: This is entirely a sales pitch, and probably not good for the community unless you can better explain why your services are what the OP needs.